# From a php cli script how do I call another interactive script?

Tags: php, shell, command-line-interface, interactive

Eg a minimal script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php 
<?php

# do some stuff and then drop into another interactive script:
system('something.sh');
```

'something' could be bash, binary, etc whatever and is interactive, like a sql/telnet/etc. In bash this is trivial. Is this even possibly inside php?

I've tried system(), exec(), passthru(), shell_exec()

proc_open() looks possible but messy to set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be interactive, `proc_open()` is **exactly** what you need.

If I recall correctly, it's the only way to get at STDIO of the child process, which you will need if you are redirecting input/output.